# Use final fields with several constructors that share code

Tags: java, constructor

I need to set some final fields from a string (essentially, by applying some regex to them, does not matter). Different constructors get this String in different ways, so a constructor looks like this

```
 public Foo(File file, Dog dog, ...)
 {
     String importantString;
     //do some stuff to get importantString
     setFinalFieldsFromString(importantString);
 }
```

Obviously, this does not work because you cannot set final fields outside the constructor. So I see two not really satisfying solutions

- Remove the "final" from the fields
- Copy&Paste the code from setFinalFieldsFromString

Is there any better approach?

Remark: As the shared code is not at the beginning of the constructor, I cannot call one constructor from the other.

Comment: show us other constructors

Comment: So if these fields need to be set after you're done doing stuff to them, why are they final?

Comment: @nbokmans I am not doing stuff to the fields, but to find the "importantString" that is used to derive them.

Comment: @krzyk All constructors look that way (with different parameters and different "do some stuff"

Comment: Can you post an actual example of your code without redactions? I can't understand your question from the post.

Comment: What is the purpose of this method ? If this is a setter, this is not useful since a final instance can't have a setter ;) If this is for readable purpose, I would use a method to do "some stuff" an return me a String instance, then instanciation the final field with this result.

Comment: setFinalFieldsFromString applies three different regex to the String, gathers the different groups and put them into five fields.

Comment: @JFMeier I know that Reflection can chang a final field (if you change the access to it), but I'm not sure this is a good idea ;) But you still can return an Array with the five value an set these into the constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [single primary constructor](http://www.yegor256.com/2015/05/28/one-primary-constructor.html) that will do final fields assignment. All other constructors will call that one using `this()`, e.g.:

```
public Foo(File file, Dog dog, ...)
    this(file, dog, getImportantString());
}
```

`getImportantString()` is needed because you can't do anything in constructor before `this()` call and also it needs to be static for it to work from the constructor.

Comment: Basicly, the primary constructor is the final Setters. That's genuis !

Comment: Yes, it is a `setFinalFieldsFromString` :)